# Combinatorially equivalent polyhedron with vertices from a given dense set

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, graph-theory, set-theory, combinatorial-geometry

In this question we are only interested in convex [polyhedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron) in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$.

Polyhedra $P$ and $P'$ are said to be *combinatorially equivalent* iff there is a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between them (denoted here as $X\mapsto X'$) preserving the number of vertices, edges and faces and their relations (i.e. edge $E$ connects vertices $A$ and $B$ and separates faces $G$ and $H$ in $P$ iff edge $E'$ connects vertices $A'$ and $B'$ and separates faces $G'$ and $H'$ in $P'$). Note that we ignore possible [chirality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality), and thus every polyhedron is combinatorially equivalent to its mirror image.

Recall that a subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^3$ is [*dense*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set)  iff there is a point from $S$ in every neighborhood of every point of $\mathbb R^3$. For example, the set of all points with rational coordinates is dense.

*Question:* Is it true that for every dense subset $S$ and every polyhedron $P$ there is a combinatorially equivalent polyhedron whose all vertices belong to $S$?

Comment: It's kinda obvious for me that it is always possible to find a combinatorially equalent skeleton, but I have doubts about faces can always be made planar.

Comment: Is there some obvious counterexample that tells us, that $S = \mathbb Z^3$ doesn't work? It seems to me that it might be enough and if that's the case, your question follows from this in a straightforward fashion.

Comment: @Stefan $\mathbb Z^3$ is not dense in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Sure, but it seems to me that your claim might hold for $S = \mathbb Z^3$ and if one can prove that, the result for dense subsets follows easily.

Comment: Actually, both theorems (for rational and integer points, resp.) are equivalent: Once you have it for $\mathbb{Q}$ an appropriate dilation will take you to the integer lattice.

Comment: But the question is about arbitrary dense set, not necessarily rationals.

Comment: @Vadimir We are aware of that, but the result for general dense sets follows, if we can prove it for integers/rationals.

Comment: Just an idea: $\mathbb Q^3$ is countable, so suppose you fix some enumeration scheme, you get a sequence of points $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$. Now suppose you drop from that sequence all points which are coplanar to three preceding points. It feels as though at least for some of the more obvious enumeration schemes the result should still be dense, but you wouldn't have any quadrilateral faces. Proving the set dense may require considerable work, though.

Comment: @Stefan It's not obvious for me how the general result for dense sets follows from the special case of rationals. Could you please give some details? You could post it as a (partial) answer.

Comment: @Vladimir I typed an answer, but had to realize, that my transformation may yield non-convex polyhedra. I think that this can be fixed, but  so far I don't see a straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. In your (deleted) answer you mentioned that by adding additional vertices any polyhedron can be transformed into a polyhedron with only triangular faces. You further assumed that those vertices can be safely removed later, after we "snap vertices to grid", restoring combinatorial properties of the original polyhedron. I think there is a problem with this step. If we started with a quadrilateral face, then after the transformation its 4 vertices might be not coplanar anymore, so they cannot become the vertices of a quadrilateral face in the transformed polyhedron.

Comment: So, a construction (or proving existence) of a dense set without a 4-element subset of coplanar points would yield the "No" answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment guided me onto the right track.

Claim. There is a dense subset $S \subseteq \mathbb R^3$ that doesn't contain $4$ distinct, coplanar points.

Proof. Fix a countable basis $\mathcal B = \{ O_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ for the topology of $\mathbb R^3$ not containing $\emptyset$ as an element. We recursively construct a sequence $(S_n \mid n \in \mathbb N_0)$ such that for all $m,n \in \mathbb N_0$ with $m < n$

- $S_m$ is finite,
- $S_m \subseteq S_n$,
- if $0 < m$, then $S_m \cap O_m \neq \emptyset$,
- no $3$ distinct points of $S_m$ are colinear and
- no $4$ distinct points of $S_m$ are coplanar.

If we manage to construct such a sequence, then $S = \bigcup \{ S_n \mid n \in \mathbb N_0 \}$ is countable, dense and doesn't contain $4$ distinct coplanar points. Towards this end let $S_0$ be any set of $4$ points that are not coplanar and such that no $3$ points of $S_0$ are colinear (e.g. $S_0 = \{(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) \}$).

Given $S_n$ let $[S_n]^3$ be the set of all subsets of $S_n$ that contain precisely $3$ distinct points. Since no $3$ points of $S_n$ are colinear, any $s \in [S_n]^3$ spans a two dimensional, affine subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ which we denote by $P_s$. Let $[S_n]^2$ be the set of all subset of $S_n$ that contain precisely $2$ distinct points. For each $s \in [S_n]^2$ let $L_s$ be the affine line spanned by $s$. Let $X = \bigcup \{ P_s \mid s \in [S_n]^3 \} \cup \bigcup \{ L_s \mid s \in [S_n]^2 \}$. Since $X$ is a finite union of sets with Lebesgue measure $0$, we know that $X$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. In particular, this yields $O_n \setminus X \neq \emptyset$. Choosing some $s_n \in O_n \setminus X$, we let $S_{n+1} = S_n \cup \{s_n\}$. $\square$

If $S$ is as in the claim, there is no polyhedra with vertices in $S$ that is combinatorially equivalent to the 'unit cube'. So your question indeed has a negative answer - contrary to my initial instinct.